# How to separate the selected item of two combobox with a single DataSource?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox, datasource

On a form, I have two combobox wich have the same DataSource (their elements list are the same). When the user select an item in one of the control, the other control's selected item is also modified. That's not what I want.

I'd like to have both list populated with the same DataSource (as I currently do), but I'd like their selected items to be independent from each other.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could use...

```
var dataSource = new[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
comboBox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
comboBox2.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Comment: They even doc'd that quite well. As astounding as I think the auto-synch behavior is, it still shows that RTFM is a must when using this framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two different instances of the data source. For this you may use the [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method:

```
var dataSource = new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource.ToArray();
comboBox2.DataSource = dataSource.ToArray();
```